# merger two query into single in mysql (one query's result is input to another query's table name)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am using two separate query for fetching result. I dont need two separate query. 
Could you please tell me in single mysql query.

Here, The first query1's result is second query's table-name..

query1

```
select `column-name1` from tablename where column-name2 ="xyz";
```

query2 :

```
select * from `column-name1` where id='$dynamic';
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't use a `JOIN` to substitute a table name, only values.

Comment: @Jacky Cheng, If I use JOIN, what will be the table name for second query as input..

Comment: If you need to do this, there's probably something wrong with your table design. Instead of having your data in different tables, you should put them all in one table, with the value you need to match against in a column.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query1 = "SELECT column_name1 FROM tablename WHERE column_name2 = 'xyz'";
$result = $db->query($query1);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc($result);
$tablename = $row['column_name1'];
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE id = '$dynamic'";
$result = $db->query($query2);
```

Comment: your correct. presently I am doing like this.. 
Is it possible to make in single query?

Comment: No, it's not. You can do it entirely in MySQL, but you have to write a stored procedure that constructs a prepared query and then executes it.